# How did Harry August find out the details of his birth?

Tags: claire-north, the-first-15-lives-of-harry-august

In *The First Fifteen Lives of Harry August* by Claire North, the titular character tells the story of his birth in detail.
Now, it is clear that at some point he can guess that he was adopted, who his biological father was, and some further information in this direction.
However, how did he get to know several details such as where his birth happened and the identity of the couple attending his birth?

Here are my thoughts on this so far:

- While Harry’s biological family was more benign to him in some of his lives, I cannot remember him reporting that they told him everything.
  And even then, they wouldn’t know some of the details or even point to the people who knew.
- Harry’s adopting parents certainly doesn’t know many of the details.
- Harry’s memory of his past lives and his mnemonic abilities only appear to kick in once he obtains consciousness.
  Thus he cannot just remember everything on account of witnessing it as an infant.
  And even then he wouldn’t have witnessed some details.
- Harry observes himself that it is rather difficult to find out the circumstances of his birth (which is an important plot point).
  Naturally, he has a headstart on this, but this only goes so far.
- It’s not just a literary device, as the entire novel is supposed to be actually written down by him.